# Expression for Additive Transform Noise

Tags: python, animation, drivers

May I reference the current property's value before an expression in an expression?
This driver expression will generate random values between -1 and 1:
`2.0 * (noise.random() - 0.5)`

If I was to add that to the current `location.x`, for example, it seems like it would be:
`self.location[0] + 2.0 * (noise.random() - 0.5)`

This however would keep adding to the `location.x` value on every frame rather than adding to the original value (before the expression). I'm used to [After Effects expressions that use `value` for this](https://youtu.be/6TKEcTHdGK8?si=_BqVmLPRFhfHKPbX&t=68).

Thank you!

Comment: A simulation zone approach is also possible: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294231/60486

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to cache variables within a driver natively, but if not you can add a custom function to the driver namespace which handles that. Run this script to install the function and just call it in the driver.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import noise

def relative_noise():
    obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

    if bpy.context.scene.frame_current == 0:
        # cache initial value at the desired frame
        relative_noise.locationx = obj.location.x
    else:
        # make noise relative to initial position
        obj.location.x = relative_noise.locationx + 2.0 * (noise.random() - 0.5)

    return obj.location.x

relative_noise.locationx = 0  # avoid a global

# add function to the driver namespace
bpy.app.driver_namespace['relative_noise'] = relative_noise
```

[image]

You can now place the object freely and it will wobble around that position.

Comment: when blender is closed and file reopened, is this saved or do we need to run the script again?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie afaik the script must be re-run. Re-opening Blender gives immediately a `NameError: name 'relative_noise' is not defined` (in the driver) in the console. Dunno how this can be improved (and would love to see, also a shorter way for caching values than mine).

Comment: oh u dont need to run it. u can just `Register` the script and it will run automatically when u open the blend file like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299887/142292

Comment: Awesome, i didn't know! Is this registration tied to the blend file?

Comment: yes only tied to this blend file 

Comment: Aaah, perfection :)

Comment: That works and I've learned so much from this post. Thank you!!!!