# How to display image inside my UI panel that receive from url in blender using python bpy?

Tags: python

I want to create a blender addon that downloads a random in the creation time of the panel on the time panel in the drawing. png file from the internet, and preview it to the user inside the panel.
The panel Info:

```
bl_label="Image"
bl_idname= "image"
bl_category="image"
bl_region_type= "UI"
bl_space_type= "VIEW_3D"
```

steps:

1. download an image from a URL,
2. preview it to the user - I'd rather store the image in the temp directory than in local storage.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Try checking [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262582/is-it-possible-to-use-external-resources-as-images/) maybe it can help you further your search for an answer. You can look into the [requests module](https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_requests.asp)